# Devise Gem in Ruby on Rails Reset password link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using the Devise gem and I have an initializer to setup mail as below:

```
   ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
       :enable_starttls_auto => true,
       :address            => 'smtp.gmail.com',
       :port               => 587,
       :domain             => 'mydomain.com',
       :authentication     => 'plain',
       :user_name          => 'info@mydomain.com',
       :password           => 'password' 
    }
```

In devise.rb I have also set the following:

```
config.mailer_sender = "info@mydomain.com"
```

The problem I have is that when I try sent the "Forgot your password" email. My application does send the email but the link to allow me to reset the email contains the gmail domain, as follows:

**http://gmail.com/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=JDKdSyhtDBkyq4Sgs2J3**

I obviously need that domain to be my application's domain so the user can reset their password. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird configuration, I usually simply set:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "example.com" }
```

In my production or development `.rb` file

---

Just understood, `config.mailer_sender = "info@mydomain.com"` is meant to fill in your `from` field.